# AHK chrome search using InputBox results in several tabs being opened

Tags: autohotkey

When I run this script below using v1.1.25.01, 
I don't get my expected result, which is to search my input value in chrome browser.

Say for example I enter the following input:

```
InputBox: Testing search query
```

and {Enter}

In the MsgBox, I get "Testing search query"

However in my chrome. It bugs out. I get 3 separate tabs that get opened. And the query in the Tabs are:

```
tab1 = http://www.google.com/#q=Testing
Tab2 = search/
Tab3 = query/
```

I am not sure why my string is being split on the spaces?

```
#Appskey::
    InputBox, UserInput, Search Query, , ,380,103
    if ErrorLevel
        MsgBox, CANCEL was pressed.
    else
        MsgBox, %UserInput%
    Run chrome.exe http://www.google.com/#q=%UserInput%
return
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the url in quotation marks to ensure it's passed as a single parameter:

```
Run chrome.exe "http://www.google.com/#q=%UserInput%"
```

By not quoting the URL, you are launching chrome with three parameters:

```
Parameter #1: http://www.google.com/#q=Testing
Parameter #2: search
Parameter #3: query
```